# Open yml file in opencv 1.0

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a yml file and i want to open the file for reading using the existing opencv 1.0 functions. The file contains something like this:

```
%YAML:1.0
Image file: "00961010.jpg"
Contours count: 8
Contours:
  -
  Name: FO
  Count: 41
  Closed: 0
  Points:
     -
        x: 740.7766113281250000
        y: 853.0124511718750000
     -
        x: 745.1353149414062500
        y: 875.5324096679687500
```

Can you please provide some example of how to iterate over this data? I need only the x, y points and store then in an array. I have searched but i did not found a similar example of data and please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to look at the [cvFileStorage](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_xml_yaml_persistence.html) data-structures, and functions.

Here is an example from OpenCV to get you started:

```
#include "cxcore.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    CvFileStorage* fs = cvOpenFileStorage( "points.yml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
    CvStringHashNode* x_key = cvGetHashedNode( fs, "x", -1, 1 );
    CvStringHashNode* y_key = cvGetHashedNode( fs, "y", -1, 1 );
    CvFileNode* points = cvGetFileNodeByName( fs, 0, "points" );

    if( CV_NODE_IS_SEQ(points->tag) )
    {
        CvSeq* seq = points->data.seq;
        int i, total = seq->total;
        CvSeqReader reader;
        cvStartReadSeq( seq, &reader, 0 );
        for( i = 0; i < total; i++ )
        {
            CvFileNode* pt = (CvFileNode*)reader.ptr;

            int x = cvReadIntByName( fs, pt, "x", 0 /* default value */ );
            int y = cvReadIntByName( fs, pt, "y", 0 /* default value */ );

            CV_NEXT_SEQ_ELEM( seq->elem_size, reader );
            printf("point%d is (x = %d, y = %d)\n", i, x, y);
        }
    }
    cvReleaseFileStorage( &fs );
    return 0;
}
```